# how to call a graph creating function in php as img src?

Tags: php, html, phpgraphlib

I wants to call a function as image src.I am drawing graph using phpgraphlib. I have tried like this but getting junk values . `

```
        <?php
         include("phpgraphlib.php");
         function  kk()
         { 
        $graph=new PHPGraphLib(1000,1000); 
        include("db_connect.php"); 
        $dataArray=array();
        $graph_array=array();
        $sql="SELECT name,mark,entered_time FROM student ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$con) ;
        if ($result) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $without_comma_value=explode(',', $row['mark']);
    $count=count($without_comma_value);

   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {
   $Val_onebyone= $without_comma_value[$i];
   $num=$i+1;
   $dataArray[$num]=$Val_onebyone; 
         } 

       }
        }

      $graph->setBackgroundColor("#F78181");
      $graph->addData($graph_array);
      $graph->setBars(false);
      $graph->setLine(true);
      $graph->setupYAxis(20, 'black');
      $graph->setupXAxis(20, 'black');
      $graph->setTextColor('black');
      $graph->setDataPoints(true);
      $graph->setDataPointColor('maroon');
      $graph->setLineColor('maroon');
      $graph->createGraph();}
       ?>
  <html>
  <form>
      <div align="center">
          <table><tr>
              <td valign="mid"><b>SpO2</b></td>
              <td align="center">
                  <img src="<?php echo kk(); ?>" />
              </td>
          </tr></table>
      </div>
 <form>
```

`When write this graph creating function on another php page and try to call that page as img src , graph is getting properly. But I want to call it as function . please help

Answer (score 0):

`createGraph()` writes directly into the output pipe of PHP. You need to cache this and echo it.

Change this last two lines

```
  $graph->setLineColor('maroon');
  $graph->createGraph();}
```

into this:

```
  $graph->setLineColor('maroon');
  ob_start();
  $graph->createGraph();
  $out = ob_get_clean();
  echo $out;
  }
```

Comment: Additionally, I don't know what `$graph->createGraph()` is supposed to print but it's probably not a URL.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, yes, it outputs the binary data of the image. IMMEDIATELY - that's the problem. But you only need it when you call `kk()`. Have you tried my code?

Comment: Hai, I have tried like as you suggested. But Showing same output like Õ?ý1ô3Ö–^ý‚ÀÉ# ..please suggest

Comment: When just calling kk() it works. but issue is on calling as a image src